# Foundation issue - tell me how worried I need to be

Tags: walls, foundation

I have noticeable movement and cracks in some of the walls in my home. This has been ongoing for a few years and seems to be getting slowly worse. The 1st photo shows the most severe and obvious evidence where it is clear that one wall is migrating down - this is in the kitchen. 2nd photo is the dining room wall opposite that first photo (other side of same wall). 3rd photo is same location as first but further away. 4th photo is a separate crack near the ceiling in the wall at the bottom of the basement stairs.

We have had significant water drainage issues directly behind the house - which is near the kitchen - which I assume may be responsible. We have recently addressed this via a landscaping job that directed rainwater around the back of the house which seems to be mostly working. Based on these photos I’m wondering how concerned I should be? Is this minor or is my house collapsing? Thanks in advance. [image: kitchen][image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think you're going to get much specific information here... if it was my house, I'd find a local professional to do a full evaluation. They'll be able to view the house in full context and make recommendations.

Comment: I agree with Aloysius - you need a pro out there in person.  It could be the foundation.  It could be a lack of proper lateral bracing.  It could be the use of overly moist green framing lumber that has dried and shrunk.  But foundation settling is fairly likely.  Which is not always dangerous, but could be.

Comment: Those are pictures of the evidence. We need pictures of the culprits (basement or crawlspace). Ideally with each picture corresponding with what's below it.

Comment: Check with the city/AHJ to find out if your home is in an area with known soil issues (e.g. expansive clay). Check with neighbors to see if they have had similar issues. These things can be fixed (with screw piers, subsurface foam, etc.) but not cheap...